# Does ZGC use more shared memory?

Tags: java, adoptopenjdk

Why does the JVM process using ZGC of OpenJDK 11 on CentOS within Docker use huge shared memory?

Server: 2 cores/4G memory;
VIRT: 17.032t, RES: 7.974g, SHR: 7.382g, %CPU: 26.9, %MEM: 199

JVM parameters:

```
-Xmx3296m -Xms1977m -Xss256k
-XX:MetaspaceSize=128m 
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m 
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseZGC 
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=50
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=80
```

After turning off ZGC, shared memory uses only 33K as below.

VIRT: 29g, RES: 1.5g, SHR: 33564, %CPU: 26, %MEM: 39.